# Command to delete directories whose contents are less than a given size

Tags: find, directory

I'm working in a directory `~/foo` which has subdirectories

```
~/foo/alpha
~/foo/beta
~/foo/epsilon
~/foo/gamma
```

I would like to issue a command that checks the total size under each "level 1" subdirectory of `~/foo` and deletes the directory along with its contents if the size is under a given amount.

So, say I'd like to delete the directories whose contents have less than `50K`. Issuing `$ du -sh */` returns

```
8.0K alpha/
114M beta/
20K  epsilon/
1.2G gamma/
```

I'd like my command to delete `~/alpha` and `~/epsilon` along with their contents. Is there such a command? I suspect this can be done with `find` somehow but I'm not quite sure how.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

With GNU `find` and GNU `coreutils`, and assuming your directories don't have newlines in their names:

```
find ~/foo -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec du -ks {} + | awk '$1 <= 50' | cut -f 2-
```

This will list directories with total contents smaller than 50K.  If you're happy with the results and you want to delete them, add `| xargs -d \\n rm -rf` to the end of the command line.

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick There is also [ncdu](http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu) that can be useful occasionally.

Comment: You probably want '-r' in the xargs command, else it will probably run once anyway?

Comment: @DavidGoodwin, not critical here as `rm -rf` won't complain if not passed any argument. There's a problem though that it works line-based instead of file-path-based. Also `du` by default deduplicates hard links and since the order of find is non-deterministic and  du may be called several times, that will be done seemingly randomly. Adding `-l` would disable that deduplication, or `+` could be replaced with `';'` for the deduplication to be done only  on each dir separately

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - I started by putting an echo before the rm bit, due to paranoia, and didn't like seeing the single "echo rm -Rf" coming out ....

Answer (score 2):

With the GNU implementations of `du`, `awk` and `xargs`, to work with arbitrary file names, you do:

```
(
  cd ~/foo &&
    du --block-size=1 -l0d1 |
      awk -v RS='\0' -v ORS='\0' '
        $1 < 50*1024 && !/^[0-9]+\t\.$/ && sub("^[^\t]+\t", "")' |
      xargs -r0 echo rm -rf --)
)
```

That is:

- specify a block size as otherwise which one GNU `du` uses depends on the environment. 1 guarantees you get the maximum precision (you get disk usage in number of bytes).
- Use `-0` to work with NUL-delimited records (NUL being the only character that may not be found in a file path).
- `-d1` to only get the cumulative disk usage of dirs up to depth 1 (depth 0 (`.`) is excluded with `!/^[0-9]\t\.$/` in `awk`.
- `-l` to make sure files' disk usage are accounted against every directory they're found in as an entry, not just the first.

Remove the `echo` (dry-run) to actually do it.

Or with `perl` instead of `gawk`:

```
perl -0ne 'print $2 if m{(\d+)\t(.*)}s && $1 < 50<<10'
```

POSIXly, you'd need something like:

```
(
  unset -v BLOCK_SIZE BLOCKSIZE DU_BLOCKSIZE
  cd ~/foo &&
   LC_ALL=C POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 find . ! -name . -prune -type d -exec sh -c '
     for dir do
       du -s "$dir" | awk '{exit $1<50*1024/512 ? 41 : 0}'
       [ "$?" -eq 41 ] && echo rm -rf "$dir"
     done' sh {} +
)
```

(the `unset -v BLOCK_SIZE BLOCKSIZE DU_BLOCKSIZE` and `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1` being for GNU `du` to make sure it uses 512 as the block size as POSIX requires).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is kind of old but I have my own $0.02 for doing this and hope it might help someone else down the line.  Using GNU parallel for much better parallel performance:

```
find . -type d | parallel du -s {} | sort -h
```

This will output all directory sizes in PWD sorted by size.  To sort reverse:

```
find . -type d | parallel du -s {} | sort -hr
```

Note that `sort -h` also works with `du -h`:

```
~  VirtualBox VMs  $  find . -type d | parallel du -sh {} | sort -h
4.0K    ./CentOS6/dir with spaces
4.0K    ./TFE79/Snapshots
8.0K    ./Desktop_default_1614944927311_69927/Logs
8.0K    ./Desktop_default_1614945289369_20675/Logs
12K     ./Desktop_default_1614944927311_69927
12K     ./Desktop_default_1614945289369_20675
96K     ./hello-world/Logs
108K    ./hello-world
160K    ./Knoppix/Logs
172K    ./Desktop_default_1627485664080_37244/Logs
172K    ./Knoppix
208K    ./CentOS6/Logs
228K    ./Flash/Logs
880K    ./TFE8/Logs
980K    ./TFE79/Logs
260M    ./NomadOS
411M    ./Desktop_default_1627485664080_37244/Snapshots
4.5G    ./CentOS6
6.6G    ./Flash
9.4G    ./TFE8/Snapshots
13G     ./TFE8
15G     ./Desktop_default_1627485664080_37244
18G     ./TFE79
56G     .
```

Comment: parallelizing tasks that are I/O bound tasks is counter productive. Also, running `du` for each dir means you're going to get disk usages of the same files several times. `du -s dir` includes the disk usage reported by `du -s dir/subdir`. Run `du` without `-s` instead without `find`. You'll need `-h` for `du` if you want human suffixes. So here just `du -lh | sort -rh` (all those -l, -h being GNU extensions and here assuming dir paths don't contain newline characters).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas "Parallelizing tasks that are I/O bound tasks is counter productive." Not always. The answer is really: "it depends, so measure instead of assume". https://oletange.wordpress.com/2015/07/04/parallel-disk-io-is-it-faster/

Comment: In practice it works much better for me anyway.  Once the metadata is cached other threads that might re-use it speed up by a significant margin.  56 threads on this box and it's about 16x faster in most of my experiences.  In my case I needed to purge small or empty garbage dirs from a web crawler so left the full min/max depth.

Answer (score -2):

First answer work well but not with dir name who contain spaces. (corrected logic because this was anything 50Kb or over)

```
#RESULTTODELETE=$(find ~/foo -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec du -ks {} + | awk '$1 <= 50' | cut -f 2-); RESULTTODELETE2=$(echo "$RESULTTODELETE" | sed 's, ,\\ ,g'); echo "$RESULTTODELETE2" | xargs rm -rf
```

Will work with :

```
~/f oo/a lpha
~/fo o/be ta
~/f o o/ep silon
~/foo/gamma
```

Comment: This looks extremely complex and brittle. Usually the recommended approach is to handle everything related to file name handling inside the `-exec`; spaces are not the only problematic character, mind you (newlines are another common corner case, though it's less often encountered in reality).

Comment: Leave out the `| xargs rm -rf` or it risks deleting data if somebody blindly copy/pastes this into the terminal.

Comment: Your problem is that you used `xargs` without `-d \\n` as per the currently accepted answer (though to be fair, it was added after you posted your answer). `-d` is a GNU extension. If your `xargs` doesn't support it but supports `-0` (another GNU extension for common these days), you can used `find... | awk... | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 rm...`